# Dynamically running SQL scripts via ADF

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory, etl

Is it possible to run simple select statements dynamically via ADF?

I want to copy tables from source to sink (sql to sql) using ADF. I am using the control table approach to load the data which allows me to dynamically load columns etc. However, for some tables I have where conditions etc or even something simple like

```
SELECT 'Apple Sauce' as ColumnABC
FROM TableA
```

Can someone please either explain or guide me to how I can create a template pipeline using control table which fulfils this requirement.

Please do ask for more information if you need.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to run simple select statements dynamically via ADF?

Yes, it is possible to run simple select statements dynamically. In copy activity there is query option which allow us to write query on table and get data from it.

**In copy activity source select `Query` type your query in query box.**

[image]